# Group multiple inputs to $_POST

Tags: php, forms, post, input

I can't figured out how to resolve this script:
At the point 1 I need to have one $data array with one ingredient, amount and um

Here is the html part:

```
...
<tr>
  <td><input name="cantitate[1]" class="cantitate" /></td>
  <td><select name="unitate[1]"><?=$display->selectAmount()?></select></td>
  <td><input name="ingredient[1]" class="ingredient" /></td>
</tr>
...
```

Here is the php part:

```
// ingredients
$ingredients = $_POST['ingredient'];
$amount = $_POST['cantitate'];
$um = $_POST['unitate'];

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ 

 $data = null;
 if(isset($_POST['ingredient']) && !empty($_POST['ingredient']) && $_POST['ingredient']!=''){

    if($key=='cantitate') $data['amount'] = $value;
    if($key=='unitate') $data['um'] = $value;
    if($key=='ingredient') $data['ingredient'] = $value;                    

    //var_dump($data);
    // point 1
    // here will be the function to add one ingredient with one um, and one amount
 }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST);` at the begin of your script if you are not sure what structure of data you are actually receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try making

```
<tr>
  <td><input name="entry[1][cantitate]" class="cantitate" /></td>
  <td><select name="entry[1][unitate]"><?=$display->selectAmount()?></select></td>
  <td><input name="entry[1][ingredient]" class="ingredient" /></td>
</tr>
```

where `1` comes from interator.

Then you can get one big array with all the requests using

```
$data = $_POST['entry']
```

and iterate thru it.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this, if I understand you correctly:

```
<tr>
<td><input name="data[]" class="cantitate" /></td>
<td><select name="data[]"><?=$display->selectAmount()?></select></td>
<td><input name="data[]" class="ingredient" /></td>
</tr>
```

and for the PHP:

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['data']);
print_r($data); //$data[0] == cantitate, $data[1] == unitate
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the fast answer, but my form it's much bigger, that's why I use for each input whit a different key. Anyway I will try also like this.